# Will adding a new feature that is sum of some other features help improve the performance of tree-based models？

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I have monthly payment features (Jan_payment, Feb_payment, ...) in my dataset. To enhance the performance of my classification model, I feel it would be useful to include a feature yearly_payment, which is the sum of 12 months' payments(= Jan_payment+Feb_payment+...). This, however, will cause perfect multicollinearity. I know perfect multicollinearity should be avoided if I want to use linear models, but should I also avoid adding such a variable if I intend to use tree-based models for classification?

Comment: Are the 12 months values in 12 rows or all in one row?

Comment: I have Jan_payment, Feb_payment.., as features in the dataset. I want to a new feature total_2022_payment that is sum of the monthy_payment features.

Comment: In that case adding another column which is just the sum of 12 other columns is pretty pointless. What do you hope to achieve with this?

Comment: It might help, yes. This seems like a likely duplicate, but I can't find something right now...